# TypeScript can not compile npm module

Tags: typescript, npm

I have an angular project which has a dependency to npm module 'module1'. When i created sysmlink for that module ln -s module1 then i was able to use it in my prject, smth like - import * as test from "module1". When I removed symlink and installed it in node_modules like npm install module1 --save and running my application i'm getting following error:

```
[11:16:00] E/launcher - Error: C:\Projects\Project\node_modules\module1\index.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export * from "./src/test.po";
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Projects\Project\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:303:16)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Project\features\steps\mytest.ts:1:1)
[11:16:00] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Could you please advise how to fix it ? (i need install module1 in my project and some how access and use *.po.ts files) Thanks.

**index.ts:**

```
export * from "./src/test1.po";

export * from "./src/test2.po";

export * from "./src/test3.po";
```

**test1.po.ts:**

```
import { browser, element, by } from "protractor";

export class test1{

    login( username: string, password: string ) {
...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that `export`there ? Can you post the .ts file ?

Comment: posted in my question above

Comment: it seems that typescript thinks that index.ts is a javascript ?!?!?!?!

Comment: hey @Mr.Sanches, it's been 3 years... did you fix this and how?